# Install4j 5.1.6 freeze on Mac 10.8

Tags: install4j

I upgraded an installer previously created with install4j 4.2.8 (it was for MacOS 10.6) by the following steps:

1. Open the installer in install4j 5.1.6 and save it;
2. Change minimum java to 1.7, and set media jre to "Installed OpenJDK JRE"
3. Check Installer->Startup->Request priviledges->Mac OS X->Try to obtain root privileges if admin user
   Then I built the installer, along with a debug version produced.

When I ran the produced dmg on Mac10.8 (with Oracle jre 7 installed), it became frozen when I clicked "Next" on the Installation Screen, and the log file stopped at output "checking writable with maximum". I could see two install4j related processes running at this point. The only way to get out the condition is to kill those processes.

I ensured that the debug version installer worked.

Please help if anyone experienced similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use jstack to get the stack traces of the two processes?

Comment: Thanks Ingo. The stack for the process owned by the logged in user can be retrieved from [StackTraceForUserProcess](http://filebin.ca/p0CUSHLwULP) , and the other process is owned by root and jstack can only get the trace by using -F, please see it from [StackTraceForRootProcess](http://filebin.ca/p0DrNWY9KEx). Sorry for the inconvenience, they are too long to fit in the comment here.

Comment: The stack trace for the root process is unfortunately just a failure of jstack. Did you execute this via sudo (otherwise it would not work)?

Comment: Yes, this is the result of "sudo jstack rootProcessPid". 

I found this may be user permission related. The problem in question occurred after I ran the "sudo debug_installer.sh" then the dmg file. I can confirm that the problem goes away if I manually delete the installation root directory created by the debug installer. I assume that there are some inconsistent context/profile between sudo and "Try to obtain root privileges if admin user" in either install4j or my own environment.

Comment: That is an interesting find!